# How to skip login on each nightwatch test

Tags: nightwatch.js

Each of my Nightwatch.js tests requires authentication in order to run and for the time being I can't make authentication to be done via cookies (of course if test fill in a username and password it logs in, but it takes time this way)

I have a working PHPSESSID (tested in Fiddler) cookie and trying to set it via nightwatch setCookie function like this:

```
browser
    .setCookie({
        name     : "PHPSESSID",
        value    : "gfnpqlflvlrkd2asj18ja2ewrt",
        path     : "/admin", //(Optional)
        domain   : "example.com", //(Optional)
        secure   : true, //(Optional)
        httpOnly : false // (Optional)           
    })        
    .url("www.example.com/admin")
```

however `www.example.com/admin` redirects me back to `www.example.com/login` meaning authentication didn't pass.

Is there any solution?

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue as well and just ended up creating a custom command. You'll need to create a new folder called custom-commands within your nightwatch test folder. In your nightwatch.JSON file you will need to specify the path to this folder like so:

```
 "custom_commands_path" : "./nightwatch-tests/custom-commands"
```

Create a new test filed in this new folder with the login steps and use the name as your new command at the beginning of each test. For example, my file is called "login.js" and it looks like this:

```
var load_speed = 5000,
local_login_url = "https://";

exports.command = function(username, password) {

  this
    .url(local_login_url)
    .waitForElementVisible('.login', load_speed)
    .setValue('input[type=text]', username)
    .setValue('input[type=password]', password)
    .click('input[type=submit]')
    .pause(load_speed)
    .assert.elementPresent('.dashboard')

  return this;
};
```

When I call the custom command in my test, it looks like this:

```
.login(username, password)
```

Comment: If you call login process every time when a new test is started - it is the hardest solution for authorization. The correct way is one login method call for auth cookie retrieving and sharing it across all tests.

Comment: Alternatively, depending on your tests, you can put this code in a "before()" block in your test module and only login once per set of tests. This works for my application currently because we test for multiple users and session data frequently and it's fine to log in and out for certain test blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the "before" or "beforeEach" hook.

http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#using-before-each-and-after-each-hooks

```
module.exports = {

  before : function(browser) {
    console.log('before all tests');
  },

  beforeEach : function(browser) {
    console.log('before each test');
  },

  afterEach : function(browser) {

  },

  "test one" : function (browser) {
    browser
     // ...
  },

  "test two" : function (browser) {
    browser
    // ...
      .end();
  }
};
```